# Running setup:di:compile Validation Without doing a Full Compile

Tags: magento2, php, di, setup-di-compile

Is there a way to run that validations from Magento 2's `setup:di:compile` **without** doing a full compile?  The `setup:di:compile` command runs a number of validations on every class file it processes. For example, it [checks that you're not declaring a dependency that exists in a context object](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/138686669515/quick-note-on-already-exists-in-context-object)

Is there a way to run these validations without doing a full compile?  The `setup:di:compile` command can take long time to run, and there's nothing more frustrating at the end of a project than

1. Run the compiler
2. Wait 5 minutes
3. See the error
4. Run the compiler again
5. Wait another 5 minutes
6. See the next error

If there was a way to run these validations stand alone it would make developers life's a bit more pleasant.

Answer (score 3):

There is `\Magento\Test\Integrity\Di\CompilerTest` in `dev/tests/static/testsuite`. It runs compiler checks on code

Answer (score 0):

Although [the code exists](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100776/4), there does not appear to be a stock, independent way to run these validations.